# Is there an elementary reason for why $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ for $p>5$ does not embed into $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p[w])?$

Tags: finite-groups, profinite-groups

This is an exercise from Serre's book on Galois cohomology.

Let $p>5$ and consider the groups $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ and $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p[w])$ where $w$ is a primitive $p$th root of unity.

Is there an elementary reason for why there can be no embedding $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_p) \rightarrow SL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p[w])?$

Of course, what counts as elementary is somewhat arbitrary. So to be more precise, I would be interested in a proof / reason which uses as little heavy machinery as possible.

Comment: It seems appropriate to mention the motivation for this question, which is, I assume, [your other question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/292988) about Serre's exercise.

Comment: $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb F_p)$ has a cyclic group $T$ of order $p - 1$ (the diagonal subgroup) and a (cyclic) subgroup $U$ of order $p$ (the upper triangular unipotent matrices) such that $T$ normalises but does not centralise $U$; but I think $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb Z_p[w])$ has no such subgroups.  ($U$ would have to consist of semisimple-over-$\mathbb Q_p[w]$ elements, at least.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb F_p)$ has a cyclic subgroup $U$ of order $p$ (the upper triangular unipotent matrices) such that some conjugacy class in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb F_p)$ contains at least $(p - 1)/2$ elements of $U$.  (This can be seen already if you conjugate only by diagonal matrices.  I don't know if the intersection has precisely $(p - 1)/2$ elements, but it doesn't seem to matter.)

Here's one argument for why $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb Z_p[w])$ has no such subgroup, though it's probably overpowered.  Suppose it does.  Then so does $G = \mathrm{GL}_2(\overline{\mathbb Q_p[w]})$.  Let $u$ be a generator of (the image of) $U$.  Since $u$ has finite order, (by the Jordan decomposition) it is contained in some conjugate of the diagonal subgroup $D$ of $G$, and (for convenience) we may arrange by conjugation that it actually lies in that subgroup.  By explicit computation, the intersection with $D$, hence *a fortiori* with $U \subseteq D$, of the conjugacy class of any power of $u$ has at most 2 elements.  This is a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
Does this use the assumption that $p>5?$ I am looking through it, but where does the argument fail for $p=5?$

Comment: It certainly doesn't work for $p = 3$, but I agree:  I don't see where it fails for $p = 5$.  Serre imposes other requirements in [the exercise you are solving](https://mathoverflow.net/q/292988), though, so it's possible that these are relevant.

Comment: Oh, I see; I forgot that $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb F_p)$ has fewer diagonal matrices than $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb F_p)$.  In fact I should have referred to a conjugacy class containing half the non-identity elements of $U$, not all of them.  Thus we need $(p - 1)/2 > 2$.

Comment: Ah, then we use all the assumptions! Thanks! I think should be seen as an elementary argument. If no other answer appears, I will accept your answer.

Comment: For $p = 5$, the group $U$ in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb Z_5[w])$ generated by $\begin{pmatrix} w & 0 \\ 0 & w^{-1} \end{pmatrix}$ satisfies the conjugacy-class condition.  I haven't been able to figure out whether it's possible to use this to build an embedding $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb F_5) \to \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb Z_5[w])$ yet, though.  (Maybe the embedding would send $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$ to $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.)